# How do I change the decimal separator in r-exams question to comma?

Tags: sweave, r-exams

I'm trying to display a comma as the decimal separator in the questions that I'm creating with the "r-exams/sweave". However, I can't load the siunitx package or do any other configuration that allows this change. I intend to export the question to moodle using the function exams2moodle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Via LaTeX packages

LaTeX packages like `siunitx` or `icomma` can only be used if the output is produced via LaTeX (e.g., `exams2pdf` etc.). However, when the LaTeX code is converted to HTML (e.g., as in `exams2moodle`) I'm not aware of a general solution of converting numbers with decimal point to decimal comma.

#### Via `options(OutDec = ",")` in R

However, what is relatively simple is to set `options(OutDec = ",")` within R. This works provided that:

1. all relevant numbers are either hard-coded in the text with a comma or produced dynamically with `r ...` or `\Sexpr{...}`, respectively,
2. it is assured that the `exsolution` in `num` exercises still uses a decimal point.

As an example, consider the `schoice` exercise [deriv2](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/deriv2/). It fulfills both items above: 1. all numbers are inserted dynamically from R, 2. it is not a `num` exercise.

```
library("exams")
options(OutDec = ",")
exams2html("deriv2.Rmd")
```

[image: deriv2]

The same also works for the Rnw version of the exercise.

If the exercise should *always* produce the numbers with a comma, you can also include the `options(OutDec = ",")` in the first code chunk at the beginning of the exercise file and revert to `options(OutDec = ".")` in a code chunk at the end.

Using the `num` exercise [deriv](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/deriv/) is also possible. But to assure item 2. you would either need to write `fmt(res, decimal.mark = ".")` instead of just `fmt(res)` in the `exsolution` or alternatively revert to `options(OutDec = ".")` before adding the meta-information.

#### Via `fmt(..., decimal.mark = "{,}")` in R

One small disadvantage of the approach above is that viewers with an attention to detail might notice that in LaTeX math mode `$...$` a small space is inserted after the comma. See the screenshot above for an example.

If you want to avoid this, then `{,}` needs to be used as the decimal separator. Unfortunately, `options(OutDec)` does not support this as it needs to be a string of length 1. Also, `OutDec` might not be enough because numbers in math mode need `{,}` while numbers in plain text need just `,`.

In this case the easiest solution is to leave `options(OutDec)` at the system default. Instead use `fmt(..., decimal.mark = "{,}")` for numbers within math mode and `fmt(..., decimal.mark = ",")` in plain text. To reduce typing you could also add two convenience functions, say:

```
cfmt <- function(x, ...) fmt(x, ..., decimal.mark = ",")
mfmt <- function(x, ...) fmt(x, ..., decimal.mark = "{,}")
```

Instead of building on the `exams::fmt()` function you could also use the function `base::format(..., decimal.mark = ...)` in case that you want to handle any rounding yourself.

#### Requirements

Note that passing `decimal.mark` to `fmt()` requires at least version 2.4-0 of R/exams.

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is that fmt(res, decimal.mark = ".") doesn't work specifically in exsolution.

Comment: Apologies, you need to use the current development version of the package (soon to be released to CRAN). I forgot that I added this feature after the last release. Simply run: `install.packages("exams", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Comment: Thanks again for the support @achim-zeileis. I did that and nothing has changed. I don't want to abuse of your goodwill but there is an additional problem with using the comma as a decimal separator. It adds extra space in the mathematical environment and this in moodle can only be solved by turning, for example, 3.14 into 3{,}14. In a latex documents this is easily resolved using the icomma package.

Comment: Re: nothing changed. Did you properly re-load the package after re-installing the package? I would recommend trying in a new session and make sure that `packageVersion("exams")` is 2.4-0. Re: comma. It is not possible in Moodle to load extra LaTeX packages, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545491/french-decimal-separator-comma-without-any-package. And in R it is unfortunately not possible to set `OutDec = "{,}"`. So as an alternative, leave `OutDec` unchanged (i.e., `"."`) and instead use `fmt(..., decimal.mark = "{,}")`.

Comment: As a personal comment: I appreciate the attention to detail and these details are the reason why I personally like to use LaTeX - but I doubt that many of your students care about it in an exam. That's why I don't bother with such fine-tuning. Although in German you would also use the decimal comma, I use a decimal point in all of my books, slides, exercises, etc. As long as students both comma and point are correctly accepted in the solutions that students enter (which is the case in Moodle) I've never had any problem with this. _(Of course, it's ok if your priorities are different, though!)_

Comment: I've added the `decimal.mark = "{,}"` solution with some further explanations to the answer. I hope this covers all relevant aspects now.

Comment: Trying to summarize the story: my moodle is configured in portuguese and accepts the correct answer with a comma as a decimal separator. I tried to present to students in the question statement that we would only use decimal separator as dot (.) in the calculations and only in the answer given to the system should be presented with comma (,). The result was not encouraging, for a simple question 25% of students dit it wrong.

Comment: Present the random values with \Sexpr{} is simple, with the Sexpr and fmt is duable, but I hope that in future we can do the same thing in a more "transparent" way without the dependence of the decimal separator string.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, okay? Your library is fantastic. I only raised this issue to make it even better.

Comment: I've edited my answer to help making the modifications easier. Re: making the package do this automatically. I don't see a sufficiently simple and robust way to do it. Replacing all "." with either "," or "{,}" is difficult because math mode has to be detected and, more importantly, "." might be used as a thousands delimiter which is even harder to auto-detect. Hence, exercise authors really have to take care of it. My answer should provide enough detail that they can make an informed choice what works best for them. If you feel that this still isn't "acceptable" that is, of course, up to you.